# Binding a property that autoupdates

Tags: c#, properties

I wasn't expecting this to work but I wanted to try it. I have a bool that should tell me if the user has selected anything in my application (inside a particular control).

I wanted to bind something to that bool:

```
        private bool _isAnythingSelected;
    public bool IsAnythingSelected
    {
        get
        {
            _isAnythingSelected = (MyModel.Series.Where(p => p.IsSelected && p.GetType() == typeof(LineSeries)).Count() > 0);
            return _isAnythingSelected;
        }
        set
        {
            _isAnythingSelected = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("IsAnythingSelected");
        }
    }
```

This is not working as I would like it, and I understand why it is so. My question is, how should I implement this selection thing without going to every method that allows user to select things? Thank you.

Comment: Can you change `MyModel` implementation?

Answer (score 1):

To update `IsAnythingSelected` properly, you have to handle two kinds of notifications:

- notification about `MyModel.Series` collection changed;
- notification about `MyModel.Series` collection *item* property changed.

The first one can be achieved "out of the box" with `ObservableCollection<T>` (or any other collection, that implements `INotifyCollectionChanged`.
The second one requires a custom solution (at least, I don't know any existing "out of the box" one).

You can combine `ObservableCollection<T>` with item property changed handling this way:

```
class MyObservableCollection<T> : ObservableCollection<T>
    where T : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private void Initialize()
    {
        // initial PropertyChanged subscription
        foreach (var item in Items)
        {
            SubscribeItemPropertyChanged(item);
        }
    }

    private void SubscribeItemPropertyChanged(object item)
    {
        ((INotifyPropertyChanged)item).PropertyChanged += HandleItemPropertyChanged;
    }

    private void UnSubscribeItemPropertyChanged(object item)
    {
        ((INotifyPropertyChanged)item).PropertyChanged -= HandleItemPropertyChanged;
    }

    protected virtual void HandleItemPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        var handler = ItemPropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(sender, args);
        }
    }

    protected override void ClearItems()
    {
        // we should unsubscribe from INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged event for each item
        Items.ToList().ForEach(item => Remove(item));
    }

    protected override void OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnCollectionChanged(e);

        // subscribe for new items property changing;
        // un-subscribe for old items property changing
        switch (e.Action)
        {
            case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add:
                SubscribeItemPropertyChanged(e.NewItems[0]);
                break;
            case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove:
                UnSubscribeItemPropertyChanged(e.OldItems[0]);
                break;
            case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Replace:
                SubscribeItemPropertyChanged(e.NewItems[0]);
                UnSubscribeItemPropertyChanged(e.OldItems[0]);
                break;
        }
    }

    public MyObservableCollection()
        : base()
    {
    }

    public MyObservableCollection(IEnumerable<T> collection)
        : base(collection)
    {
        Initialize();
    }

    public MyObservableCollection(List<T> list)
        : base(list)
    {
        Initialize();
    }

    public EventHandler<PropertyChangedEventArgs> ItemPropertyChanged;
}
```

...and make `MyModel.Series` a `MyObservableCollection<T>` instance.
Then, your class, which contains `IsAnythingSelected`, will look like this:

```
// somewhere in code, where `MyModel` being initialized:
MyModel.Series.CollectionChanged += (sender, args) => RaisePropertyChanged("IsAnythingSelected");
MyModel.Series.ItemPropertyChanged += (sender, args) => RaisePropertyChanged("IsAnythingSelected");

    public bool IsAnythingSelected
    {
        get
        {
            return MyModel.Series.Any(p => p.IsSelected && p.GetType() == typeof(LineSeries));
        }
    }
```

You even don't need `IsAnythingSelected` to be read-write property in this case. Just notify, that it was changed, and binding engine will re-read its value.